# Why is gl.drawArraysInstanced unable to draw more than one shape in subsequent calls?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl2

I'm using WebGL2 and trying to call gl.drawArraysInstanced for drawing multiple shapes. The first call of gl.drawArraysInstanced can draw 2 or more elements.

> gl.drawArraysInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices, 3);

I then call the same function 3 sec later but it only draws one triangle. (see example below)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');

var cube = {};
var vertices = [
  -0.2, -0.2, 0,
   0.2, -0.2, 0,
   0.2,  0.2, 0,
];
var numVertices = vertices.length / 3;

var vertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vertexShader = getAndCompileShader('vertexShader', 'vertex');
var fragmentShader = getAndCompileShader('fragmentShader', 'fragment');
var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

var vao = gl.createVertexArray();
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'position');
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

function getAndCompileShader(id, shaderType) {
    var shader;
    var shaderElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var shaderText = shaderElement.text.trim();
    shader = gl.createShader(
        shaderType==='vertex' ? gl.VERTEX_SHADER : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER
    );
    gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderText);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return true;
    }
    console.log('Shader ' + id + ' compiled.')
    return shader;
}

function start() {
  gl.clearColor(.5,0,0,1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
  gl.drawArraysInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices, 2);
  console.log('Drawing 2 triangles');
  setTimeout(function() {
    gl.clearColor(.5,0,0,1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArraysInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices, 2);
    console.log('Drawing 2 triangles again');
  }, 3000);    
}

start();
```

```html
    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
#version 300 es
in vec3 position;

void main() {
    if(gl_InstanceID==0) {
        gl_Position = vec4(position.x - 0.2, position.yz, 1);
    } else {
       gl_Position = vec4(position.x + 0.2, position.yz, 1);    
    }
}
    </script>
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
    finalColor = vec4(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);;
}
    </script>
    
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 200px" width="600" height="400"></canvas>    
    </body>
```

Also, is calling **gl.drawArraysInstanced** supposed to be more efficient than **gl.drawArrays**?
Thanks

Comment: I see 2 triangles both times. To verify I set the clear color the second time to something else.

Comment: Maybe this problem is specific to the environment. I'm on a Mac, and I see this problem both on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I'm on Mac as well, Mid 2014 MBP, macOS 10.13.2. https://imgur.com/BYXOQkX. It's possible it's a bug in your driver. Are you on the latest OS? If not upgrade. If you're already on the newest maybe it's still a bug in your driver and you should file a bug. Maybe even consider adding a webgl conformance test to see if other GPU/Drivers have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Once the drawing is complete, the gl.useProgram(null) needs to be called.

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.clearColor(.5, 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
  gl.drawArraysInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices, 2);
  gl.useProgram(null);
  console.log('Drawing 2 triangles');
  setInterval(function () {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
    gl.drawArraysInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices, 2);
    gl.useProgram(null);
    console.log('Drawing 2 triangles again');
  }, 3000);
```